# Without pam (Pluggable Authentication Modules) how linux system will behave?

Tags: linux, centos-6, pam

Suppose if we create nologin file under /etc then only root can login, but if we comment on all pam_nologin.so line in every file under /etc/pam.d/ then other user also login.

That means these /etc/nologin,/etc/securetty are all controlled by pam only (I guess)

Without PAM how can I achieve the same thing?

OR

Describe the system with PAM and without PAM

I am using CentOS 6.2

Comment: Can you explain what you are hoping to accomplish, or why you don't want to use PAM to accomplish it?  It is difficult to know what possible solutions to offer, without knowing what restrictions you are trying to maintain.

Comment: ok, Then just describe the linux system with PAM and without PAM.